# Serializing Dataset in c# using NewtonSoft.JSon

Tags: c#, json

My scenario is like this. I've a dataset that has 2 tables inside and 1st table has rows but the 2nd table has empty that meaning that it has no records. When i serialized it using newtonsoft.json, it serialized the 1st table data only but i need 2nd table also with empty values meaning that  so that i can deserialize this to another dataset so that it can have 2 tables with 1 table with data and another table with no data. This is done in C#
Code is below

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "TblService";

dt.Columns.Add("Service_Id");                    
dt.Columns.Add("Service_Name");

dt.Rows.Add("1", "AAA");
dt.Rows.Add("2", "BBB");

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

DataTable  dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.TableName = "Service_Method";

dt1.Columns.Add("Id");
dt1.Columns.Add("Service_Id");
dt1.Columns.Add("Method_Name");

//dt1.Rows.Add("", "", ""); If I use this I get 2 tables serialized. But I want without using this step.

ds.Tables.Add(dt1);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Here is the json value  :

```
{
    "TblService": [{
        "Service_Id": "1",
        "Service_Name": "AAA"
    }, {
        "Service_Id": "2",
        "Service_Name": "BBB"
    }],
    "Service_Method": []
}
```

and this is not having any data about table 2.

Comment: The JSON snippet is OK. You forgot to add any data to the second table. How do you expect anything to be serialized ?

Comment: Are you confusing a row with empty strings for "empty values"? Empty strings *are* strings, with a very specific content and size. If you want to have `Service_Method` contain a record with empty strings, you'll have to add a row that contains those empty strings

Comment: If you don't have any data to insert, initialize data table with default values.   so that you will get json string with empty values.

Comment: Thnx panagiotis. i think u did nt see that i commented the line dt1.Rows.Add("", "", "") in mypost . if i uncommeent it then that its also serialized. But as we have complex datasets that have many tables , i just want to automate that so that even empty tables are also serialized. coz when i want to create a new dataset with this serialized data thsi dataset is not having empty tables in its datatables collection.

Comment: Thnx Suchit. But here i can't initialize datatable with default values as the dataset is already created somewhere else and passed here and its a complex one with many tabels . Otherwise i ve to loop through each table checking it has any rows or not and add empty row if it has none. i want to avoid that .

Comment: used newtonsoft.json and its serializing and deserializing the datasets even with empty datatables as needed.Thnx for ur support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used newtonsoft.json and its serializing and deserializing the datasets even with empty datatables as needed.Thnx for ur support